In SDK style project, how to use InitialTargets if the task is imported by PackageReference
I am migrating a project to SDK style project. There is an InitialTargets defined as:
    <Project InitialTargets="TargetReadFiles" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
         <Import Project="$(PkgMSBuildTasks)\tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
        ...
         <Target Name="TargetReadFiles" >
        ...
          <Zip Files="@(DirectoryObjectFiles)" ZipFileName="$(ZipOutputFile)" Flatten="true" />
        ...
        </Target>
     </Project>

The target contains a Zip task whose definition is in MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets
When I convert this project to SDK format and build the project, the build fails because it tries to resolve the Zip task first before importing MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets. The error message is error MSB4036: The "Zip" task was not found.
  <Project InitialTargets="TargetReadFiles" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> 
       <ItemGroup>
         <PackageReference Include="MSBuildTasks">
          <GeneratePathProperty>True</GeneratePathProperty>
         </PackageReference>
       </ItemGroup>
       <Import Project="$(PkgMSBuildTasks)\tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
      ...
      <Target Name="TargetReadFiles" >
       ...
       <Zip Files="@(DirectoryObjectFiles)" ZipFileName="$(ZipOutputFile)" Flatten="true" />
       ...
      </Target>
 </Project>

How can I force import of MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets file so that definition of Zip task can be found?

The cause of the MSB4036 error is not that the task is used before the Import. Imports are always done before Targets are run. MSBuild has two phases: evaluation and then execution. Imports are performed in the evaluation phase. Targets are run in the execution phase. The InitialTargets are used to determine the order that targets will be run in during the execution phase.

Have you run a restore to get the MSBuildTasks package?

Are you targeting .Net Framework in your project? It looks like MSBuild.Community.Tasks is targeted to and built for .Net Framework 4.0.

@JonathanDodds Yes, I ran restore to get the MSBuildTasks package. Yes, I am targeting .Net Framework 4.8 in this project.
The package restore fails with the error error MSB4036: The "Zip" task was not found. If I remove this InitialTargets, then the package restore succeeds.

Okay - that actually makes sense. Restore itself is a target. When you run msbuild -t:restore (or an equivalent), the TargetReadFiles target will be run before the Restore target. Try the following: Remove InitialTargets and change <Target Name="TargetReadFiles" > to <Target Name="TargetReadFiles" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">.

If the zip file is not needed for compilation and if the @(DirectoryObjectFiles) item collection is expected to be files created during compilation, then the target has been running far too early. Something like the following may be better: <Target Name="TargetReadFiles" AfterTargets="AfterCompile">

Removing InitialTargets and adding BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" resolved the issue for me. Thanks!
